# Is relying on initialization state of PHP properties bad design?

Tags: php, rest, model, initialization

I've looked far and wide on how to properly check whether a property is initialized in PHP, only to find that it's not recommended, and should be avoided, hence there is no built in `is_initialized` PHP function (although `array_key_exists` achieves this for arrays).

One use case that I have not seen mentioned anywhere is partial updates of objects, and I can't find a good solution to this that does not rely on initialization.

Let's imagine a User:

```php
class User {
    private int $id;
    private string $firstName;
    private ?string $lastName;
    private ?string $phoneNumber;
    
    // constructor and getters/setters
}
```

Now, I want to have an endpoint where you provide **only the values that you want updated**, e.g. something like:

```json
{
    phoneNumber: null
}
```

The expected behavior here, would be to replace the current `$phoneNumber` with null.

Now, I can parse the JSON to an array, or our custom DTO:

```php
class UserInput {
    public string $firstName;
    public ?string $lastName;
    public ?string $phoneNumber;
}
```

Now I have an issue with nullable properties. I only requested the `$phoneNumber` to be changed to null, but I want to tell a difference between a requested null, and an unrequested property, in this case, to differentiate that `$phoneNumber` is meant to be overwritten in the User with null, but `$lastName` is not meant to be changed. Goal being a simple mapping:

```php
if (array_key_exists('phoneNumber', $array) {
    $user->setPhoneNumber($array['phoneNumber']);
}
```

My solution is to check if a given property is initialized, using `array_key_exists` in case of an array, or `ReflectionClass::isInitialized()` or custom implementation of `is_initialized` for the DTO.

So my question is - is this bad design, or is this a valid case where relying on initialization state could be considered fine?

Comment: How about [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware isset() would return false for an initialized null, but we want to use that null as it's a valid value in this scenario.

Comment: There is [no real difference in PHP](https://www.exakat.io/en/the-three-nothings-of-php/). I find your question quite confusing. It seems like you're trying to transfer a concept from another language to PHP.

Comment: I'll try to update the question to clarify it better. The idea is that a JSON requested $phoneNumber to be set to null, while it didn't request any other changes. If we rely on isset(). With isset, there is no way to tell a difference between $dto->phoneNumber, which is null, and $dto->lastName, which is uninitialized, so it shouldn't be changed, contrary to phone number which should be used to overwrite current User phone number to null.

Comment: Well, in that case you can only set the properties for which you get a name in the JSON string. You already know you can do this with `array_key_exists()` or something similar.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes. An official `is_initialized()` method was not implemented, because they considered it bad code design to rely on initialization state, and if you really want to use it you have other options. My question is whether this code relies on initialization state because it's designed poorly, or if it's an actual use case where it makes sense and is not bad code design.

Comment: There is no code in your question that does anything close to relying on an initialization state, which makes it hard to understand what you're talking about. That being said: `null` is the same as not being initialized. So if something is a string, and you want it to have no value, use an empty string: `$phoneNumber = "";`, that way you can distinguish it from a property that hasn't yet received a value. I guess I really don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: Initialise the property with a value which never will be (and cannot be) entered by a user, like "\u{0028}". Or instead of the built in string type use your own string class.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware An empty string might have been the input. A null might have been the input too. Both of these tell me "overwrite the current User value with the one requested". In case of an uninitialized property, I know "ignore it, no changes were requested". To me, that's relying on initialization state, because I try to differentiate between value given and no value given.

Comment: @lukas.j That might not always work, for example an integer where all values are considered valid. I prefer to use an array and array_key_exists, or ReflectionClass, but the idea here is if it's bad design to even rely on any of these, or if it's fine in a case like this.

Comment: Seems like separate properties are the wrong tool here. Since they are private and you're using setters and getters, why not just have one array as property and add the properties as key/values in that array when they are set? Then you can simply check if the key exists in the array or not. There's no reason to make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @AdamJacyno That is true, but in the case of ints: the applications where for example PHP_INT_MAX or PHP_INT_MIN are valid values are probably rather rare (unless these applications deal with math).

Comment: @M.Eriksson Is using array_key_exists any different than hypothetical is_initialized though? Of course one exists and the other doesn't, but logically both do the same thing - tell us if something is initialized - making the code rely on initialization state either way, arguably. On the discussion of whether to add is_initialized (https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/7029), one of the arguments against adding it, compared is_initialized vs isset issue, to array_key_exists vs isset

Comment: _"is there a way to achieve the same behavior without relying on initialization state"_ - That's what I gave you. I don't understand what your point of the last comment is. I don't care what someone says/suggests etc in some pull-request. I'm here to answer/give suggestions on the question at hand. You said it yourself, key_exists() exists, while is_initialized() doesn't. And what is "bad design" is highly subjective and shouldn't be used in a blanket statement. It's all situational. If partial updates solves a problem without causing other issues for you, then it's not bad design.

Comment: @M.Eriksson My point was that I would consider "array_key_exists" to be exactly the same as is_initialized, meaning both of these rely on initialization state (one of key in the array, the other of property in an object), but that was definitely unclear in the question. 

I was more focused on good/bad design part. There often seems to be consensus whether something is or isn't a bad design, or when it is or isn't, and I meant to mainly focus on that. To me this seems like an okay approach, but thought that maybe it's an already solved problem with an objectively better solution.

Comment: I think the question is quite poorly written, forcefully suggesting an impossible solution without clearly describing the problem. An [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: _"My point was that I would consider "array_key_exists" to be exactly the same as is_initialized, meaning both of these rely on initialization state (one of key in the array, the other of property in an object), but that was definitely unclear in the question."_ - I don't see the point of even talking about it since "is_initialized" _isn't a thing_ in PHP atm.

Comment: _"There often seems to be consensus whether something is or isn't a bad design, or when it is or isn't"_ - There are certain things that are more or less regarded by most (most, not all) as bad design. It's essentially things that are suboptimal to solve the problem and has side effects. The side effects can be things like not solving the problem, adding new problems, bad performance (when it's noticeable/causing issues) or maintainability.  Other than that, it's all highly subjective and situational.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I updated the question to make my original intent clearer, should be better now hopefully - in the end, my intent is to know whether I walked into a "known" bad design case, that I might be missing (it looks like a valid use case for me), or if it looks like an okay solution.

Comment: The code in your question is still very minimal. Where does `$array` come from? My guess is from the JSON, but I am not sure. What if any other value needs to be set? Once you actually work out the code you can probably use a loop and it will all fall into place.

Answer (score 1):

> Is relying on initialization state of PHP properties bad design?

I'd say yes, because PHP has no really clean and performant way to determine this. You can determine [isInitialized()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.isinitialized.php) via reflection, but that's not recommended for a process that's going to be hit so frequently.

Regarding the situation of "how do I know which fields to update", there are lots of ways to handle that:

- If you're already parsing the JSON to an array, then the simplest answer is pretty obviously that you don't need a custom DTO and you can just use `array_key_exists()`.
- If you want a skeleton DTO just to apply typehinting, then you could rely on the quirk that *uninitialized public properties don't get iterated over when casting to a traversable*. I don't think this is the best idea however, because it's likely not guaranteed to keep working this way. It's very simple though:

```php
class User
{
    public ?string $phone;
}
$user = new User();
foreach ($user as $name => $value) {
     echo "1st run: $name is initialized\n"; // outputs nothing
}
$user->phone = null;
foreach ($user as $name => $value) {
     echo "2nd run: $name is initialized\n"; // outputs "2nd run: phone is initialized"
}
```

- If you want a DTO that does some basic validation, you could make the DTO properties protected, create setters for them, and then maintain a separate protected attribute that explicitly tracks which fields have been set:

```php
class User
{
    protected array $initialized = [];
    protected ?string $phone;
    public function setPhone(?string $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = some_process_to_validate_and_format($phone);
        $this->initialized ['phone'] = true;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is array_key_exists really any different from ReflectionClass::isInitialized from good/bad design point of view (so skipping the performance issue which could be avoided if we had a dedicated implementation here)?

Using foreach to map values works, and seems to be how something like Symfony maps it. This becomes an issue if your input is not 1:1 with backend though, especially when Input is complex and requires a lot of Backend logic to handle, but that's another issue I guess.

Comment: @AdamJacyno - If performance isn't a thing, then sure, go with reflections if you want. I would argue though that adding complexity to your code when you know it isn't needed, is in all cases I can think of, a bad idea (performance + maintainability wise). My view on good code is code that does what it suppose to do in a as clear and straight forward manner as possible. If you have a specific _issue_ that restricts certain solutions, then please share that.

Comment: _"Is array_key_exists really any different from..."_ Yes. It's one function call. It's simple. It's extremely fast. It's readable, clear, and concise. Maximize the amount of code not written.